Existence of a lower-bound for an interesting function!
Suppose that $$h(x,z):= (x-z)^T\nabla f(z)+\frac{1}{2}(x-z)^TH(x-z),$$ where $f$ is a smooth function in $\mathbb R^n$. Also, suppose $H\succ 0$ and $\|\nabla f(u)\|\le \gamma; \forall u\in \mathbb R^n$. Can we conclude that $h$ is bounded below for all $(x,z)\in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$?
I am trying to avoid imposing other conditions (for example convexity on $f$, having a lower bound for $f$ itself, or even bounding $x$ and $z$ to a bounded set) to achieve the existence of a lower bound but if we have to, that is okay.
If we consider the KKT conditions, we see that at a local minimizer, taking gradient with respect to $x$ and setting it equal to zero implies $x-z=-H^{-1}\nabla f(z)$ and therefore the following:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
h(x,z)
&=
(x-z)^T\nabla f(z) +\frac{1}{2}(x-z)^TH(x-z) 
\\ 
&
=
 -\nabla f(z)^TH^{-1}\nabla  f(z) + \frac{1}{2} \nabla f(z)^TH^{-1}\nabla  f(z)
\\ 
& 
=
 -\frac{1}{2}\nabla f(z)^TH^{-1}\nabla  f(z)
\\ 
&\ge 
 -\frac{1}{2} \|H^{-1}\|_2 \|\nabla f(z)\|_2^2
\\
& \ge 
-\frac{1}{2} \lambda^{-1}_{\min}(H) \|\nabla f(z)\|^2
\\
& \ge - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^2\lambda^{-1}_{\min}(H)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
But does this necessarily mean that the whole function $h(x,z)$ is bounded below?
By the way, setting the gradient of $h$ with respect to $z$ equal to zero shows that $(\nabla^2 f(z)-H)(x-z)=\nabla f(z)$.
Is $h(x,z)$ coercive?

Let
$c := \frac14\lambda_{\min}(H) > 0$.
By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz and AM-GM, we have
$$(x-z)^\top\nabla f(z)
\ge - \sqrt{\|x-z\|^2 \|\nabla f(z)\|^2}
\ge - 2c \|x-z\|^2 - \frac{1}{8c}\|\nabla f(z)\|^2.$$
Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
 h(x, z) &\ge - 2c \|x-z\|^2 - \frac{1}{8c}\|\nabla f(z)\|^2 + \frac12(x-z)^\top H (x - z)\\
 &= \frac12(x-z)^\top (H - 4c I)(x - z) - \frac{1}{8c}\|\nabla f(z)\|^2\\
 &\ge - \frac{1}{8c}\gamma^2.
\end{align*}

This is amazing and smart! Thank you!

@Sam You are welcome.

Would you please see this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4901225/bounding-a-sequence-related-to-minimizers-of-strictly-convex-quadratic-functions. Thank you!
